# Do opponents' Pokémon's Power Points deplete?

Tags: pokemon-stadium

I know that in Gen 1 games, the opponent's Pokémon has infinite Power Points.

Was this fixed for Pokémon Stadium 1? I tried to search on Google for an answer but couldn't find anything.

Comment: For anyone even DARING to think what I'm thinking, PP stands for Power Points in Pokémon!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was fixed for Pokemon Stadium. I own the game, and can recall battles where the opponent ran out of PP and stopped using said moves. In fact I beat Prime Cup R2 by PP stalling the Mew's Softboiled and Psychic.

The only opponent that has infinite PP is Mewtwo (both R1 and R2). Given its status as the final boss against an entire team of Pokemon, this is likely by design.